# Oracle DB LIKE query on NULL values

Tags: sql, oracle

This question is about Oracle DB. I want to know how Oracle DB query LIKE clause works on NULL values.

```
Select * From table_name where column_name like 'text%'
```

In above query, how the Oracle db treat to rows with null value for column 'column_name'? Also how about 'NOT LIKE'.

Also, I observed that rows having NULL values are not selected for the following query.

```
Select * From table_name where column_name NOT LIKE 'text%'  .
```

I don't know why rows having NULL values for the column are not in results even though they are null and hence not like 'text%' .

Comment: `NULL` essentially means 'unknown', so `NULL` is `not like 'text%'`, but it is also not `like 'text%'`

Comment: Null isn't even equal to Null :  NULL=NULL -> False

Comment: @AmirPelled - That is incorrect. To deal with NULL, SQL (and with it, Oracle) uses three-valued logic, and NULL=NULL is "UNKNOWN". If it was FALSE then its negation would be TRUE, which is not how NULL works. That is: if NULL = NULL was FALSE, then NOT (NULL = NULL) would be true, which it isn't. Both are UNKNOWN and both will make a condition to "fail" ("success" is TRUE, "fail" is either FALSE or UNKNOWN).

Comment: You are probably thinking about "NULL is the same as the empty string - so why doesn't NULL NOT LIKE 'text%' succeed?" If that is really your question, I couldn't agree more - and Oracle says they may sometime in the future distinguish between NULL and empty strings. For now, in most (but not in all!) situations an empty string is treated as an actual NULL, and there is no way to make an empty string act like an empty string (that is a string that is known to be empty with 100% certainty, not a NULL that in principle could be anything).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NULL` values basically fail all comparisons.  The general idea is that `NULL` means "I don't know what the value is".  So, when you use `like` with the pattern `'text%'`, the answer is "I don't know what the value is".  It is `NULL`.

And if you use `not like`, the answer is the same "I don't know what the result is".

That is how `NULL`s work.  Even with `like` and `not like`.  Even with Oracle.

Comment: NULLs also don't show up if your search pattern is '%'.

Answer (score 1):

**First one**,
  When you search for `column_name like 'text%'`, db search for string that starts with "text" not other string, it doesn't matter what will come after the `text`. It could be anything like `text123,text stack` etc.

**Second one**,
  When you search for `NOT LIKE 'text%',` db search for all the columns that should not be started with `text`, it the column value have text it will not be in the result. it is like `"atext"`, it will be appear in the search results.

So in both condition **NULL** values never match so they don't come in the results.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

### **Try this,**

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE NVL(column_name,1) NOT LIKE NVL('',2) -- '' OR NULL you can use
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE NVL(column_name,1) NOT LIKE NVL('',2) -- '' OR NULL you can use
```

Comment: Why have you answered this twice? The `nvl('',2)` might as well just be `2`, so you're saying `like 2` - it doesn't make sense to use `like` for numbers, and the question is clearly about strings; or to use it without any wildcards. Using a magic value (1, or an actual string) isn't a good idea either really. If you're sure the value won't ever match, why is that better than `where column_name is null`?